# How to add text between jquery datatable pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, datatables

I am trying to add datatable info i.e "Page 1 of 1" between pagination text. Is it possible to achieve this?

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  pagingType: "full",
  pageLength: 5,
  info: true,
  language: {
    info: "Page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",
    paginate: {
      previous: '<',
      next: '>'
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Check this: https://jsfiddle.net/7ramuk9c/1/

Comment: I want to datatable info details between the pagination buttons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your code:

I edit my code to fit your case. Also it appears that datatable need to keep the original info element in order to do the update after you switch to another page, so you need to clone it to the new place instead of cut and paste, and set hide

```
drawCallback: function( settings ) {
    $(".dataTables_paginate").children(':eq(1)').after($(".dataTables_info").hide().clone().css({'display':'inline-block', 'float': 'unset'}));
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/96oy3buk/3/